# If $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=1$ prove inequality: $\frac a{b^2 +c} + \frac b{c^2+a} + \frac c{a^2+b} \ge \frac 94$

Tags: inequality

If $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=1$ prove inequality: $$\frac a{b^2 +c} + \frac b{c^2+a} + \frac c{a^2+b} \ge \frac 94$$

Comment: I tried this already but I could not get to a solution..

Comment: Please stop asking answerers to delete their answers. If you posted a question from an exam, you should be prepared to deal with the consequences.

Answer (score 6):

since
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{a}{b+c^2}=\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{a^2}{ab+ac^2}$$
Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,we have
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{a^2}{ab+ac^2}\right)\cdot\sum_{cyc}(ab+ac^2)\ge\left(\sum_{cyc}a\right)^2=1$$
so we only prove this following inequality
$$\dfrac{1}{\sum_{cyc}(ab+ac^2)}\ge\dfrac{9}{4}$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow 4\ge9\sum_{cyc}ab+9\sum_{cyc}ac^2$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow 4(\sum_{cyc}a)^2\ge 9\sum_{cyc}ab+9\sum_{cyc}ac^2$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow 4\sum_{cyc}a^2\ge \sum_{cyc}ab+9\sum_{cyc}ac^2$$
since
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2\ge \sum_{cyc}ab$$
so we only prove this
$$3\sum_{cyc}a^2\ge 9\sum_{cyc}ac^2$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \sum_{cyc}a^2\ge3\sum_{cyc}ac^2$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \sum_{cyc}a\cdot\sum_{cyc}a^2\ge3\sum_{cyc}ac^2$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \sum_{cyc}a^3+\sum_{cyc}ab^2\ge 2\sum_{cyc}ac^2$$
since Use AM-GM inequality
$$\sum_{cyc}a^3+\sum_{cyc}ab^2=\sum_{cyc}(a^3+ab^2)\ge\sum_{cyc}(2a^2b)=2\sum_{cyc}ac^2$$
By done!

Comment: @math110 how is your argumentation before the first "since" ?

Comment: @user133853: First, it is the policy of this site not to delete good content. Second, users have put effort into answering your question and deserve the credit they get.

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

Multiplying a in the numerator and the denominator, you get

$$LHS = \frac{\sum a^{2}}{\sum (ac+b^{2}a)}$$
Applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality  in the below steps

\begin{align}
&\geqslant\frac{(\sum a)^{2}}{\sum ac + \sum b^{2}a}\\
&\geqslant \frac{1}{\sum ac + \frac{1}{3}\sum a \sum a^2} = \frac{1}{3\sum ac +\sum a (\sum a)^2}\\
&\geqslant \frac{3}{\sum ac + (\sum a)^{2}}
\end{align}

Applying the inequality $$\sum ac \leqslant \frac{1}{3} (\sum a)^{2}$$

$$LHS \geqslant \frac{9}{4}$$

Edit: @9rm, Apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequlality to $$\sum b^{2}a \leqslant (\sum b^4)^\frac{1}{2}\cdot (\sum a^2)^\frac{1}{2}.$$ This will reduce to $$\leqslant (abc)^\frac{1}{2}\cdot \sum a\cdot \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}({\sum a})^{2}.$$ This will further reduce to $$\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\cdot \sum a\cdot \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\cdot {\sum a}^{2} = \frac{1}{3}\cdot \sum a(\sum a)^{2}.$$

Comment: I did'nt get the step where you used $\sum a \sum a^2 \ge 3\sum b^2a$ .. can you please explain :)

Comment: The first step seems to be using the "identity" $$\sum_k\frac{a_k}{b_k}=\frac{\sum\limits_ka_k}{\sum\limits_kb_k}$$

Comment: @9rm as I understand it,that is wrong replacing $a=b=c=1/3$. Maybe it means something else,and that is why I have never liked this notation.

Answer (score 0):

By C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+c^2}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{ab+ac^2}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(ab+a^2b)}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$4(a+b+c)^2\geq9(ab+ac+bc)+9(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)$$ or
$$4(a+b+c)^3\geq9(ab+ac+bc)(a+b+c)+9(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(4a^3-6a^2b+3a^2c-abc)\geq0$$
and since by AM-GM $\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2c\geq3abc$, it remains to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^3-3a^2b+a^2c)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^3-3a^2b+ab^2)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}a(a-b)(2a-b)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(a(a-b)(2a-b)-\frac{1}{3}(a^3-b^3)\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(5a+b)\geq0.$$
Done!