# Prove that $\frac{a}{b^2 + c}+\frac{b}{c^2 + a}+\frac{c}{a^2 + b} \ge \frac{3}{2}$ when $a+b+c=3$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I've tried solving [Pham Kim Hung's](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h145137p821727) famous inequality problem which he posted on aops in April 2007 for 2 days now. This is the problem: Show that $$\frac{a}{b^2 + c}+\frac{b}{c^2 + a}+\frac{c}{a^2 + b} \ge \frac{3}{2} \tag{*}$$
when $a, b, c > 0$ and $a+b+c=3$.

I've tried with many theorems and tricks (like AM-GM, C-S, etc.) but haven't really figured out a way.

The closest I could get was by solving a [similar problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2523191p21416375) like this.

So, if you know the proof of (*) please share here. I'd be much thankful to you.

Comment: if fact, there's generalisation to this,$ \frac {a}{\sqrt {kb + c^2}} + \frac {b}{\sqrt {kc + a^2}} + \frac {c}{\sqrt {ka + b^2}} \ge \frac {3}{\sqrt {k + 1}}$    (when a+b+c=3)

Comment: you can view that here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h300129

Comment: Equality is achieved when $a=b=c=1$, which should probably give a hint.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/JiTAtGE

Comment: you might use The Cauchy Reverse Technique

Comment: You must add the condition $a,b,c$ positive because for example if $(x,y,z)=(1,-2,4)$ then $LHS\lt\dfrac32$

Comment: This has been asked and answered before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/703518/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4149973/42969

Comment: @MartinR The first one is quite different. In the 1st one, the usual (obvious) Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz $(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{a}{b^2 + c}) (\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} a(b^2 + c)) \ge (a + b + c)^2$ works. However, it does not work here.

Comment: What about the second one?

Comment: @MartinR The 2nd one is the same as this topic. If this topic is not closed, I will give another proof different from Michael Rozenberg's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+c^2}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^4}{a^3b+a^3c^2}\geq\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{\frac{1}{3}(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2+\frac{1}{3}(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}=\frac{3}{2}$
(For numerator we use Titu's Lemma and simplify denominator :) )

> Thanks to [arqady](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/user/12908)
> For more information vist https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h401290p2234611

Comment: But it is arqady's proof. (+1) Anyway. By the way, I use the Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz in the same way but the remaining is different from arqady's.

Comment: Thanks :). I guess he is MSE too.

Comment: @RiverLi You seem to have a beautiful inequality in your profile ;)

Comment: In MSE, he is Michael Rozenberg. You may correct the spelling aquardy (arqady).

Comment: Thanks. It is No. 3 of Xuezhi Yang's 22 conjectures in inequalities (Mr. Yang is a Chinese scholar).

Comment: @RiverLi Out of curiosity, do you have a link to this list of 22 conjectures about inequalities? I am also amazed by the inequality in your profile description.

Comment: @Prism https://www.doc88.com/p-4405905284406.html  (Chinese). OR https://www.docin.com/p-456874670.html (Chinese).

Comment: @Prism You are welcome.